# Inject big values in XML tag with xmlstarlet or whatever

Tags: xml, shell

I am trying to modify a tag value from an xml with `xmlstarlet ed` but I can't figure out how could make it works with big values...

I am trying to update the tag `Article_texte` with the full source code of intranet pages downloaded with `curl`

Here an extract of my_xml that contains URLs (linuxgizmos.com for test purpose)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<DOCUMENT>
  <Article_url>http://linuxgizmos.com/raspberry-pi-stays-sky-high-in-2015-hacker-sbc-survey/</Article_url>
  <Article_texte />
</DOCUMENT>
```

Here an extract of my shell script

```
# extract url from file
url_to_dl=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/DOCUMENT/Article_url" my_xml.xml)

# download and update document
xmlstarlet ed -L -u "/DOCUMENT/Article_texte" -v "$(curl -Ls $url_to_dl 2>&1)" my_xml.xml
```

This second command line goes on error :

> /usr/bin/xmlstarlet: Liste d'arguments trop longue

I spent my day with that ****, some help will realy be appreciate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, why someone downvote the question -_-' ?

For now, I found a "solution" not very sexy but it does the trick

```
if [ -f "$xml.insert" -a -s "$xml.insert" ]; then
  echo "merging ..."
  # the tag <Article_texte/>  should be on the form : 
  # <Article_texte>
  # </Article_texte>
  sed -i -e "s#<Article_texte\s*\(/>\|></Article_texte>\)#\n<Article_texte>\n</Article_texte>\n#" $xml

  # we load the content of `$xml.insert` file after the opening tag
  sed -i -e "/<Article_texte>/ r $xml.insert" $xml

  rm -f "$xml.insert"
fi
```